# 5 ma to 2 amp variable current circuit using TIP120 BJT. Please analyze my circuit and comment

Tags: power, transistors, current, dc, variable

I'm trying to build a circuit that can output current from 5ma to 2Amps using BJT TIP120. Voltage is 18v and constant.

I tried designing a simple circuit. Please check the image below and let me know your comments. Thanks in advance.

[image: 18V 0 to 2Amp Current Regulator]

Comment: Transistor will get very hot very fast. At half range it will be dissipating more than 9W.

Comment: Thanks, so using a heatsink should resolve the issue or any changes in the circuit required to deal with heat. As per the specs, the BJT is capable of 5A!

Comment: It won't likely output much more than 50mA and what it does output will vary greatly with the sample of TIP120 and will be unstable. If you do get it to work at higher currents by changing values the current will change dramatically as the Darlington heats up. As you have no requirement for stability or accuracy perhaps that's fine with you.

Comment: Since you're not using the transistor as it's meant to be used, you're using it as a rheostat. Which leads me to a question, why don't you just use a buck converter or turn a potentiometer into a rheostat by shorting the middle pin with one of the outer pins? Also, there's no feedback happening which means that as the temperature changes, the current will change and you will have to change the potentiometer all the time.

Comment: Thanks, Spehro. Could you please tell me how you calculate 50mA value... yes, stability or accuracy is not that important for me.

Comment: I looked at the typical gain of the TIP120 at the low end and multiplied by the approximate base current. The E-B resistors mean that gain drops off rapidly with base current.

Comment: Hi Harry Svensson. The reason for not using a buck converter is not so pure DC output. I have two questions here: 1: you're not using the transistor as it's meant to be used 2: turn a potentiometer into a rheostat by shorting the middle pin with one of the outer pins

Comment: Spehro Pefhany, one more question. by E-B resistor, did you mean a resistor connecting emitter lead to base lead. If yes, then I did not use a  E-B resistor...

Comment: Thanks for all your comments and teaching me a lot of new things. I'm an average electronics hobbyist. I'll try building the circuit and post back the status.

Comment: @conamx Put a fat inductor of several Henries in series with your load then. You can probably take apart a microwave oven and use one of the coils in its transformer. I doubt that you can see any of the noise on your load with that setup.

Comment: If I had to use a potentiometer, then it should be atleast 36W....That's why I would better deal with heat off the transistor. However, my main concern is the BJT is rated at 5A, wouldn't it be able to handle 2A with heatsink...

Comment: The first thing that strikes me about this question is the ratio: \$\frac{2\:\textrm{A}}{5\:\textrm{mA}}=400\$! Getting near three orders of dynamic range. Anytime someone asks for that... with a single TIP120 circuit?? ... I get antsy. Do they really need that range? And if so, do they need a log-lin type of control system?

Comment: Your circuit shows an 18V 36W LED. Is that what you are intending to drive?

Comment: @Bruce Abbott, yes 18V 36W LED

Comment: @jonk. 2A is not mandatory. how much current that the TIP120 can handle comfortably and how much base current should be provided at the base terminal. Please let me know.

Comment: @conamx Perhaps you don't know what you are saying when you write 5 mA to 2 A? That, plus other things you wrote, all suggests you want to be able to adjust the value between those two end points. A problem here is having he ability to double the current from 5 mA to 10 mA, and at the same time being able to double the current from 1 A to 2 A. How do you plan to be able to specify a 5 mA change in one case and a 1 A change in the other? A potentiometer would require a subtle hand on the knob, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by doing your homework - looking at the transistor data sheet. Like [this one](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/TIP120.pdf). Pay attention to Figure 1 "DC Gain". Notice how the gain drops off at low base currents?

So, how much base current can you expect? Well, a Darlington base-emitter path has two junctions in series, so figure about 1.4 volts across it for a fairly wide range of base currents. This leaves 16.4 volts across your input resistor/pot combination. With the pot turned to zero, the base resistance is 120k, so your maximum base current will be on the order of $$i = \frac{V}{R} = \frac{16.4}{120k} = .14\text{mA} $$

What does this mean for this transistor? Look at Figure 1. At a collector current of 0.1 amps, a typical gain is about 400. Since gain is collector current divided by base current, $$Ib = \frac{Ic}{G} = \frac{100{\text{mA}}}{400} = .25\text{mA} $$

In other words, you would need twice as much base drive as you are providing just to get 100 mA of load current. And this is a conservative number, since figure 1 shows the gain drops with decreasing current, so I would guess that your circuit would produce a maximum of about 30 mA.

The only benefit I can see is that you won't need to worry much about heat-sinking the transistor. Of course, the bulb won't be glowing, either.

Comment: thank you. one more question, before I accept the answer. Assuming the pot turned to zero and if I use a 8k resistor, will it output stable 2A if proper heatsink is used ...

Comment: @conamx - You've seen how to calculate base current needed for a given collector current. Do so with a 2 amp current. Then calculate the base current you'd expect with an 8k resistor and see if that is greater than what you need.